# R XML package, namespace for getNodeSet

Tags: r

I am trying to learn a bit of scraping with R through the XML package but just get empty docs and vectors when trying to extract given a certain Xpath (extracted as done in this tutorial : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tuNuxCjBU3U).
I tried to use rvest but the selector tool on Chrome is not able to select some of the elements (or groups them and does a mess).

I understand, from other posts, that the problem is the namespace, but I do not understand how should I set a namespace.

The following is my current effort:

```
url<-"https://www.imdb.com/chart/top"
doc1<-htmlParse(url)
rating<-getNodeSet(doc1,'//*[@id="main"]/div/span/div/div/div[3]/table/tbody/tr/td[3]/strong')
```

given the xpath: //*[@id="main"]/div/span/div/div/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[3]/strong stripped of the [3] after "tr" to be able to get all the same elements and not just the single data point.

What would be an appropriate way to find the namespace and set it?
Many thanks!
Sam

Comment: Scraping IMDB is a violation of Amazon's terms & conditions as well as a deliberate bypass of their robots.txt technical control.  Please don't ask SO contributors to engage in unethical behaviour.

Comment: Most of the tutorials found on the web use IMDB as basic website to perform such exercises.

Comment: No, they do not. _Some_ clueless ones _do_ and that doesn't give anyone the right to violate terms of service or technical controls. Ethics matter.